# All possible sums in an array and the projection of the combinations

Tags: c++, sum, combinations

Well, first of all I am a newbie to C++ programming, second I have a problem to solve that seems to give me a headache. It goes like this. I have a `char[3][14]` (`user_in` in my code) and I get input from the user to fill it. User types only `'1','x','2','*'`. For example:

```
1**
1*2
**2
*x*
1**
1**
*x2
**2
**2
1x*
1**
*x*
**2
1**
1x2
```

Then I transform this array into another `int[3][14]` (`user_in_tr` in my code). For every `*` I put `0`, for `1` I put `1`, for `x` I put `2`, for `2` I put `3`. So:

```
1**  100
1*2  103
**2  003
*x*  020
1**  100
1**  100
*x2  023
**2  003
**2  003
1x*  120
1**  100
*x*  020
**2  003
1**  100
1x2  123
```

The thing I want to do is to count all the possible sums, taking one element from each row. Notice that the element must not be 0. So wherever there is 0 we skip it. In my example it would be:

```
First:  1+1+3+2+1+1+2+3+3+1+1+2+3+1+1=26
Second: 1+1+3+2+1+1+2+3+3+1+1+2+3+1+2=27
Third:  1+1+3+2+1+1+2+3+3+1+1+2+3+1+3=28
Fourth: 1+1+3+2+1+1+2+3+3+2+1+2+3+1+1=27
```

And so on...

Max sum = 42 (14x3), Min sum = 14 (14x1)

Also I want to show the numbers that were added.
I have came up with some code but the results are not those ones that I expected here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    char user_in[3][14];
    int user_in_tr[3][14]
    int i,j;
    int count0,count1,count2,count3,count4,count5,count6,count7,count8,count9,count10,count11,count12,count13;
    int sum;

    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            scanf("%c",user_in[j][i]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<14;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(user_in[j][i]=='*')
            {
                user_in_tr[j][i]=0;
            }
            else if(user_in[j][i]=='1')
            {
                user_in_tr[j][i]=1;
            }
            else if(user_in[j][i]=='x')
            {
                user_in_tr[j][i]=2;
            }
            else
            {
                user_in_tr[j][i]=3;
            }
        }
    }

   for(count0=0;count0<3;count0++)
   {

     for(count1=0;count1<3;count1++)
     {

      for(count2=0;count2<3;count2++)
      {

       for(count3=0;count3<3;count3++)
       {

        for(count4=0;count4<3;count4++)
        {

         for(count5=0;count5<3;count5++)
         {

          for(count6=0;count6<3;count6++)
          {

           for(count7=0;count7<3;count7++)
           {

            for(count8=0;count8<3;count8++)
            {

             for(count9=0;count9<3;count9++)
             {

              for(count10=0;count10<3;count10++)
              {

               for(count11=0;count11<3;count11++)
               {

                for(count12=0;count12<3;count12++)
                {

                 for(count13=0;count13<3;count13++)
                 {
                  sum=0;

                  if(user_in[count0][0]!=0&&user_in[count1][1]!=0&&user_in[count2][2]!=0&&user_in[count3][3]!=0&&user_in[count4][4]!=0&&user_in[count5][5]!=0&&user_in[count6][6]!=0&&user_in[count7][7]!=0&&user_in[count8][8]!=0&&user_in[count9][9]!=0&&user_in[count10][10]!=0&&user_in[count11][11]!=0,user_in[count12][12]!=0&&user_in[count13][13]!=0)
                  {
                   sum=user_in[count0][0]+user_in[count1][1]+user_in[count2][2]+user_in[count3][3]+user_in[count4][4]+user_in[count5][5]+user_in[count6][6]+user_in[count7][7]+user_in[count8][8]+user_in[count9][9]+user_in[count10][10]+user_in[count11][11]+user_in[count12][12]+user_in[count13][13];

                   printf("%d",sum);

                   printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",user_in[count0][0],user_in[count1][1],user_in[count2][2],user_in[count3][3],user_in[count4][4],user_in[count5][5],user_in[count6][6],user_in[count7][7],user_in[count8][8],user_in[count9][9],user_in[count10][10],user_in[count11][11],user_in[count12][12],user_in[count13][13]+"\n");
                  }
                 }
                }
               }
              }
             }
            }
           }
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output does your code give?

Comment: Some things - (1) I fixed your indentation. (2) Why `int count0 ... for (count0 = ...` instead of `for (int count0 = ...`? I'd only use the prior when the latter doesn't compile (i.e. in C), or I want to access the variable outside the loop. (3) Either indent nested for-loops or stay away from curly braces (`{}`) there. For one thing, 14 lines of `}` with the same indentation isn't great. (4) Don't be afraid of spaces, e.g. change `for(count0=0;count0<3;count0++)` to `for (count0 = 0; count0 < 3; count0++)`.

Comment: Are you putting any whitespace (space, newline) when inputting?

Comment: i press enter in order to type the new character

Comment: Also I 'm wondering if there is an easier way to accomplish my goal, without using 14 embedded fors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you might consider solving your problem is using recursion.  Although not always good practice, recursion on this problem significantly improves readability (only 1 for loop for processing the data).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<unsigned> Row;
typedef std::vector<Row> Data;

void load_user_data(Data& data);
void calculate_sums(unsigned value, Data::const_iterator begin,
        Data::const_iterator end);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Data data;

    load_user_data(data);

    calculate_sums(0, data.begin(), data.end());

    return 0;
}

void load_user_data(Data& data)
{
    // WARNING: Untested, but should read data from user
    /*for (unsigned i = 0; i < 14; ++i)
    {
        Row temp;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        {
            char input = '\0';

            while (input == '\0')
            {
                std::cin >> input;
                switch (input)
                {
                case '1':
                    temp.push_back(1);
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    temp.push_back(2);
                    break;
                case '2':
                    temp.push_back(3);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    break;
                default:
                    input = '\0';
                }
            }
        }

        data.push_back(temp);
    }*/

    // Because I'm slightly lazy, the code bellow loads your data
    // into the vector Data.  If you had C++11 you could use
    // initializer lists.  If you want to try the code above,
    // comment out the code bellow.

    Row t;

    t.clear(); t.push_back(1); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(1); t.push_back(3); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(3); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(2); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(1); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(1); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(2); t.push_back(3); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(3); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(3); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(1); t.push_back(2); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(1); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(2); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(3); data.push_back(t);
    t.clear(); t.push_back(1); data.push_back(t);

    t.clear(); t.push_back(1); t.push_back(2); t.push_back(3);
    data.push_back(t);
}

void calculate_sums(unsigned value, Data::const_iterator begin,
        Data::const_iterator end)
{
    if (begin == end)
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for (Row::const_iterator entry = begin->begin();
            entry != begin->end(); ++entry)
    {
        calculate_sums(value + *entry, begin+1, end);
    }
}
```

If you want to show the numbers added, you could replace `unsigned value` with a vector you add your numbers to in each iteration, then you could display the sum and the components.  If I get a chance I will add an example to the above code.

**EDIT:**  The following piece of code will output the full sums (including both the numbers and result).  The only difference from the previous code is that you are now storing the combinations so that you can display them latter, this is achieved by passing a `std::vector` (a list) to the function `calculate_sums` (previously we only passed on the running total value).  Hope this helps.

```
void calculate_sums(const Row& values, Data::const_iterator begin,
        Data::const_iterator end);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Data data;

    load_user_data(data);

    Row temp;
    calculate_sums(temp, data.begin(), data.end());

    return 0;
}

void load_user_data(Data& data)
{
    // Same as above
}

void calculate_sums(const Row& values, Data::const_iterator begin,
        Data::const_iterator end)
{
    if (begin == end)
    {
        int value = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
        {
            value += values[i];
            std::cout << values[i] << char((i < values.size()-1) ? '+' : '=');
        }
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for (Row::const_iterator entry = begin->begin();
            entry != begin->end(); ++entry)
    {
        Row temp(values);
        temp.push_back(*entry);
        calculate_sums(temp, begin+1, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said before I am a newbie to c/c++ programming so I can't keep up with your code yet(Data data;,typedef for example :P) I m going to read about what i don't know(i ve got some books!) in order to understand what you coded. Thank you for your help, and sorry for my ignorance...

Comment: I tested yor code and it works pretty well(and the part that was commented out).

Comment: I would be grateful if you send me the code example you mentioned before. I would really like to examine it and understand vectors better.

Comment: @ios_32 I have updated my answer with the code to output the full sum.  This is probably not the best code to be learning about vectors from, but I hope this helps you to understand vectors a little better.  Good luck learning C++.